# Module to parse RSS feed in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, rss, cck

I'm trying to simply display an RSS feed as part of my site. A user will put in an RSS URL into a CCK field and I want to take that URL and display the latest RSS results.

I assume there's a module for this but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5):

http://drupal.org/project/feeds will do this and a lot more.

Here's a good video to get started

http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/dec/15/importing-and-aggregating-stuff-feeds

Regarding your request about integrating with CCK, I don't know how you can do that but that may not be necessary because the feed URL is entered through a dialog of its own. And you can always add other CCK fields to the Feeds Content type.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the simplepie module and used the function `simplepie_get()` included within.

Answer (score 0):

The main feed aggregators are the the core [aggregator](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/aggregator) module, [feedAPI](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi) module, and the newer [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module. I'm not sure any of them are set up to integrate with CCK in quite the way you're describing. I suspect that will require some custom development.

If you don't need the feed data in the Drupal database, you could use a javascript library to bring in the feeds on the client side.